# rspec test just runs entire program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm only a few days into learning rspec, and I'm trying to write my first test in a program that contains classes. I know this test is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it because I don't get a failure. Instead, it just starts running through my program (a simple tic tac toe game). I left out the code for the tic tac toe game for brevity. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
require "tictactoe"

describe Game do
  describe "#players" do
    it "displays player names" do
      player1 = "Harry"
      expect(Game.new("Harry", "Nick").players).to eq(player1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you do e.g. `ruby tictactoe.rb` does it run your entire program? If it does, then `require "tictactoe"` is also going to run your entire program.

Comment: yes running ruby tictactoe.rb will run my program. I had done this because for all the other practice specs I wrote, I had included the file with my ruby code as well. Should I not do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discovered in the comments above, the problem is that `tictactoe.rb` has the code that runs your entire program, so `require "tictactoe"` also runs your entire program.

There are two solutions.

The first is to change `tictactoe.rb` to only execute the code that causes the entire program to run when your script is executed from the command line and not when it's `require`d from another script. This is a common idiom in Ruby:

```
# declare your classes up here
class Game
  # ...
end

# etc...

# down here run the program only if this
# script is run from the command line
if __FILE__ == $0
  game = Game.new
  # ...and so on...
end
```

Now you can `require "tictactoe"` in your tests, knowing that the code in the `if` block won't be executed.

The second solution is to move your class declarations into other files, e.g. put the Game class in `game.rb` and have `tictactoe.rb` do `require "game"`, and have the RSpec code that tests the Game class do the same.

The latter approach is more maintainable as programs get larger. If you look at a large gem like, say, Bundler, you'll find that the "program" file, `bundle` only has a few lines of code—all it does is `require` other code that does the real work.

However, if your program is small and you don't anticipate it growing much in the short term, the former approach is just fine, too.

Comment: I don't have enough points to upvote your response, but it helped me immensely towards getting on the right track. Thanks so much for showing me that trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First, `require rspec` at the top of your file.

```
require "tictactoe"
require "rspec"

RSpec.describe Game do
  describe "#players" do
    it "displays player names" do
        player1 = "Harry"
        expect(Game.new("Harry", "Nick").players).to eq(player1)
    end
  end
end
```

Then make sure you run your file with `rspec` NOT `ruby`

so

```
rspec foo.rb
```

Comment: This did not work. I have a feeling it has something to do with calling Game.new in the expect statement, but I don't know how else to go about doing it because the player names get initialized as instance variables when Game.new is called. From there I want to be able to call the #players method to then make sure that the names of the players will be puts'd to the screen.